# Mongo complicated group

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("522f05f06f92046814003b84"),
        "personal_id" : "0609150071",
        "superstructure_id" : 1,
        "name" : "David",
        "surname" : "Bar",
        "plays_often" : 1,
        ...
        "created" : ISODate("2013-09-10T13:43:38Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("522f05f06f92046814003b84"),
        "personal_id" : "0609150071",
        "superstructure_id" : 1,
        "name" : "David",
        "surname" : "Bar",
        "plays_often" : 1,
        ...
        "created" : ISODate("2013-09-10T14:11:55Z")
}
...
```

and need find records with:

- criteria: `superstructure_id: 1`
- grouped by `personal_id`
- from these groups return only the newest record base on `created` field
- and then sort all group results by `plays_often`
- with limit 5

so result will have only this record with `"personal_id" : "0609150071"` because has newer datetime in `created`:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("522f05f06f92046814003b84"),
        "personal_id" : "0609150071",
        "superstructure_id" : 1,
        "name" : "David",
        "surname" : "Bar",
        "plays_often" : 1,
        ...
        "created" : ISODate("2013-09-10T14:11:55Z")
}
```

Is this possible in mongodb?

Comment: Take a look at [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate).

Comment: Ok I have this but how can I do the newest date filtering?

db.goalie_tables.aggregate([ {$match: {superstructure_id: 1} }, {$group: {_id: "$personal_id", personal_id: {$addToSet: "$personal_id"}} } ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will not contain the entire original document. Instead, it contains a `doc_id` field which is the `_id` of the original document. The final `$project` operator will rename some of the fields to match the input documents. For example, the `$group` operator renamed `personal_id` to `_id`, so `$project` changes it back.

```
db.goalie_tables.aggregate({
  // Only select documents where superstructure_id = 1
  $match: {
    superstructure_id: 1
  }
}, {
  // Sort the documents for each personal_id in descending created date order
  $sort: {
    personal_id: 1,
    created: -1
  }
}, {
  // Select the first document (ie, most recently created) for each personal_id
  $group: {
    _id: "$personal_id",
    doc_id: {
      $first: "$_id"
    },
    plays_often: {
      $first: "$plays_often"
    }
  }
}, {
  // Sort the results by plays_often (descending)
  // Change to 1 for ascending
  $sort: {
    plays_often: -1
  }
}, {
  // Limit to 5 documents
  $limit: 5
}, {
  // Rename fields:
  //   _id => personal_id
  //   doc_id => _id
  //   plays_often => plays_often
  $project: {
    _id: "$doc_id",
    personal_id: "$_id",
    plays_often: "$plays_often"
  }
});
```